# Firebase on iOS: Initialising FIRApp without GCMSenderID possible?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm initialising `FIRApp` in my iOS App using the `configureWithOptions` api as follows:

```
FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithGoogleAppID:@"x:xxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxx" bundleID:nil GCMSenderID:@"xxxxxxxx" APIKey:nil clientID:nil trackingID:nil androidClientID:nil databaseURL:@"https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com" storageBucket:nil deepLinkURLScheme:nil];

[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

This is being done in order to dynamically instantiate it with minimal required parameters obtained through the app's server without having the Firebase plist file added to the app's `Xcode` project. However, if I omit `GCMSenderID` by setting it as nil, the app gives an exception when running it. Why is the `GCMSenderID` required in the code above & is there any way to work without it? Kindly let me know. Thanks in advance!